# onclick find text on page and scroll to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrolltop

I have a website with an online store that is embedded and automatically populated so I have no access to actual code. When the store populates, it compiles all my items together with headings for seperate item categories.

My idea is to build a menu that uses the onclick function to find some text on the page (the item category headings) and scroll down to that category since I can't simply use `<section>` or scroll to `div` by id.

Here is the site as it sits right now: www.monumentalmarketingllc.com/storetest

I'm currently trying to get this to work without any luck:

```
<a href="#" onclick="beerequipment()">BEER</a>

<script>
    function beerequipment() {
        $(window).scrollTop($("*:contains('BEER EQUIPMENT'):last").offset().top);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Never use anchor as button, use span instead, on anchor you must prevent default action and that's just unessecery code. Also I don't encourage you to use inline JS because it's bad practice instead of that you could use e.g. `$('a').click(function() { Your code ... });` of course use span and give it a class to prevent function from  firing on every span click ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the `a` tag will keep the page at the top because of the # href. Try changing it to a button, or some other element:

```
<button onclick="beerequipment()">BEER</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u32me/

Comment: I might get flamed for this but, since the `<a>` isn't used for a website link but as a javascript button, a clickable `<div>` with an onclick event handler would work without any need to manage the extraneous `href` attribute here. Making it a button might require extra styling. then again, people hate clickable divs because they don't convey "semantics", though I think that point is moot in this case.

Comment: Makes sense to me IvyLynx :)

Comment: lol thanks, I was expecting a million downvotes instead of upvotes :P

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
href="#"
```

to

```
href="javascript:void(0)"
```

full example:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="beerequipment()">BEER</a>

    <script>
        function beerequipment() {
            $(window).scrollTop($("*:contains('BEER EQUIPMENT'):last").offset().top);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault()` method to stop the default action of `<a>` from happening.

Try this:

Change `a` tag to this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="beerequipment(event)">BEER</a>
```

JQuery:

```
function beerequipment(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(window).scrollTop($("span:contains('Beer'):last").offset().top);
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BZKHh/1/)**

Comment: This seems to work great on your demo, but I can't get it to work for the life of me. Here's a link to my test site with your code: http://www.monumentalmarketingllc.com/storetest/

Comment: Put that script at the bottom of the HTML not at the top.... or use an external file for that script